# How to grep lines that end with .c or .cpp?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a file as below, I want to grep for lines having `.c` or `.cpp` extension. I have tried using `cat file|grep ".c"` grep but I am getting all types of extensions as output. Please shed some light on this. Thanks in advance.

```
file contents are below:
/dir/a/b/cds/main.c
/dir/a/f/cmdss/file.cpp
/dir/a/b/cds/main.h
/dir/a/f/cmdss/file.hpp
/dir/a/b/cdys/main_abc.c
/dir/a/f/cmfs/file_123.cpp
```

Comment: What do you mean by "o/p" ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`grep` supports regular expressions.

```
$ grep -E '\.(c|cpp)$' input
```

- `-E` means 'Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression'
- `\.` means a dot `.`
- `()` is a group
- `c|cpp` is an alternative
- `$` is the lineend

Comment: Both answers are correct and more-or-less the same.  egrep is identical to grep -E

Comment: @sree So just to clarify, the problem was that `.` means `any character` so your grep matched anything that had `any character followed by a c`. To get rid of matches like `.cpp` you have to say that the string needs to end after `c`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ grep -E '\.cp{2}?' testfile1 
/dir/a/b/cds/main.c
/dir/a/f/cmdss/file.cpp
/dir/a/b/cdys/main_abc.c
/dir/a/f/cmfs/file_123.cpp
$
```

May be this variant will useful. Here `p{2}` mean 'symbol p meet 2 times after symbol c'

Comment: This would match `foo-.cpp-bar`, too. The `?` is not necessary with `{0,2}`.

Comment: @Tichodroma good find. But `?` need bacause `main.c` not in results.

Comment: @Tichodroma I fix bug with `'\.cp{2}?'` regexp. Now filter only `c` and `cpp` files. `cpp-bar` not in result.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use `--include` parameter like below

```
grep --include \*.hpp --include \*.cpp your_search_pattern
```

Answer (score -1):

The Android framework defines a bash function extensions named `cgrep`, it goes recursively in the project directory, and it's much faster than using `grep -r`.

```
Usage:
cgrep <expession to find>
```

it greps only C/C++ header and source files.

```
function cgrep()
{
    find . -name .repo -prune -o -name .git -prune -o -type f \( -name '*.c     ' -o -name '*.cc' -o -name '*.cpp' -o -name '*.h' \) -print0 | xargs -0 gre     p --color -n "$@"
}
```

You can paste this in you `.bashrc` file, or use the inline directly in shell.

Comment: We are not talking about recursing into folders. The input is simple text file.

Comment: @Tichodroma you're right, I just reread the question. I will delete my post